# How to get plain price value with amazon In-App Purchasing API

Tags: java, android, in-app-purchase

Is there any way to retrieve the numerical price value of a purchase Item (`API v1.0`) or Product (`v2.0`) in the Amazon In-App Purchasing API for Android. I need the pure price value as a number without the currency symbol to do some calculations over a list of items.

In google and samsung billing API I can get the value and currency separately but not for amazon where it is just a formatted price string with localized currency symbol.

If there is no way in `API v1.0` or `v2.0`. I need a stable parser to extract the value independently from any possible currency notation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, as far as I know, there is no way to directly retrieve a numerical value of a purchased items or product item price. As you said, all you can get is a String price, containing the currency symbol.

To my opinion, the easiest solution is to use a regexp to extract the value from the price string. I'm no regexp expert, but I would do something like that, I think it covers most cases:

```
// Explanations about the regexp:
// \\d+: match the first(s) number(s)
// [\\.,\\s]: match a "separator": a dot, comma or space
// \\d+ (the second one): match the number(s) after the separator.
// The lasts two are englobed in []*, as they can be repeated 0 or n times.
Pattern     patternPrice = Pattern.compile("(\\d+[[\\.,\\s]\\d+]*)");

double extractPrice(String price) throws InvalidParameterException {
    Matcher     matcher = patternPrice.matcher(price);

    if (matcher.find())
    {
        String      match = matcher.group();

        // proceed post treatments to convert the String to a Double
        // delete space from price if any
        if (match.contains(" "))
            match = match.replace(" ", "");

        if (match.contains(","))
        {
            // price contains one comma and one dot: price format is something like that : 1,000,000.00
            // OR
            // there is more than one comma in the price (price is something like that 1,000,000)
            // so delete the , from price
            if (match.contains(".") || match.length() - match.replace(",", "").length() > 1)
                match = match.replace(",", "");
            // price simply use a comma to mark the decimal part, replace it by a . for Double.parseDouble method.
            else
                match = match.replace(",", ".");
        }

        return Double.parseDouble(match);
    }
    else
        throw new InvalidParameterException(price + " is not a valid parameter.");
}
```

Some tests I performed to check my solution:

```
Input  : $1.79
Output : 1.79

Input  : 3,59€
Output : 3.59

Input  : $ 2.89
Output : 2.89

Input  : $ 1.5
Output : 1.5

Input  : 1,99 €
Output : 1.99

Input  : 1€
Output : 1.0

Input  : $4
Output : 4.0

Input  : 45£
Output : 45.0

Input  : 4,000.00 ¥
Output : 4000.0

Input  : 1 000.00€
Output : 1000.0

Input  : 1,000,000¥
Output : 1000000.0

Input  : 1,000,000.1¥
Output : 1000000.1

Input  : 2 355 825.837¥
Output : 2355825.837
```

Hope it helped!

Comment: Some additional information: Amazon delivers a non breaking space character between value and currency symbol. Your code works on standard java sdk but not on android devices. On android the matcher does not remove the nbsp, so I had to add some additional handling to remove the nbsp before parsing the value.